# How to make a shader similar to Subway Surfers or Talking Tom Gold Run in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I am trying to make an endless runner similar to Subway Surfers. I got the perfect textures and models but I can't seem to find or make a toon shader that doesn't flatten my textures since I have gradients in my textures to make my game look toony.

I've tried unity's default "Toon/Basic, Toon/Lit, Unlit/Texture" shaders but they flatten my texture gradients making my game not smooth. Also, when I apply these shaders, the lighting doesn't even have the slightest impact on the models.

I expect my game to look similar to Subway Surfers or Talking Tom Gold Run since I have the perfect models but the shader plays a big part in the material and is a big problem.

Images:
[My Game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnqIU.png)
[Talking Tom Gold Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hei5M.png)

Comment: It would help if you included images in the question that illustrated what you have now and what you would like to achieve.

Comment: I just added pictures of my game and Talking Tom Gold Run. Compare the two pictures.

Comment: Your game is missing shadows. It looks like talking tom uses fake projected shadows of some kind, and all the other lighting is baked into the textures. So.. not a shader problem, more of a content problem.